# Spring JPA Exception Translation

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have configured my application context as stated in the spring documentation to enable Exception Translation from jpa exceptions to spring DataAccessException. Should I also provide the implementation of PersistenceExceptionTranslator? If so, can anyone give me an example of how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

I do it only by putting the @Repository annotation on my DAO or Manager class that uses the EntityManager. 
Make sure that you enabled component scanning:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable exception translation as well as repository scan by using following xml configuration

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.nagarro.ncpp.backend.repository" />
```